# When & Why should I use Dependency Injection tokens in angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have come across the use of InjectionToken in injecting environment veriables (plain objects) into a service.
I am somewhat confused as to why and how should tokens be used in Dependency Injection.
I have search over google for phrases suck as "When to use InjectionToken" and "Why should I use InjectionToken" and I have yet to come across an article that explains the need for InjectionToken.

My understanding is... that generally tokens are used to resolve a conflict between 2 primitives that evaluate to the same value in DI making one of them being ignored by the injector. However the subject is still very vague to me.

Why should token be used in DI?
or When should tokens be used in DI?
Refrences to articles about this will also be appriciated.

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/dependency-injection-and-providers/tokens/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you use class/type as an injection token, it works most of the time.

However, sometimes you don't want to expose class/type or simply want to inject raw object/array/primitive value/function/independent interface implementation. In these cases solution is to use injection token (since there are no corresponding types/classes), it is like using lookup by unique name vs lookup by class/type.